# Software allowing one to play with various permutation groups?

Tags: group-theory, education, math-software

An example of a game that is a permutation group is rubix cube. It is illustrative to see an example of a permutation group.

It would be nice if there is a game/piece of software that includes various permutation groups and gives the user the ability to apply any element of the group, form combined elements and see how they combine, etc.

Does such software exist?

Comment: [Give "Group Explorer" a try.](http://groupexplorer.sourceforge.net)

Comment: @Shaun, I've looked at group explorer. It's definitely good, thank you. But (see my question) I'm looking for something interactive, where the user can apply the permutations, and see what happens.